# How can I debug a memory leak for a loopback application on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, loopbackjs, strongloop

We have a quite nasty memory leak going on in a loopback (node.js) app, but it does not seem to happen locally, only on Heroku.

It steadily increases memory usage without any requests, and I fired up 10 000 requests locally without seeing a similar pattern.

[image: heroku memory usage]

I currently have no good ideas for how to debug this further.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out disabling New Relic fixed the issue. We had log level set to debug to figure out another issue, and suddenly all hell broke loose. They do indeed have a notice on their documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a blog post from Strongloop dealing with memory leak profiling [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-tip-of-the-week-memory-leak-diagnosis/).  It goes over installing heap dump and how to use Chrome dev tools to collect heap snapshots on the client side using the JavaScript console built into the browser. Analysis of the heap can be done within this same console as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am already dumping heap dumps to s3 every hour and investigating the dumps with dev tools, but it was rather hard to take decisive action on the data.